# count where equals 1

Tags: php, laravel

I have a question, is it possible to count where **estado** is = 1?

```
$array = Tickets::groupBy('rrpp')->selectRaw('rrpp, count(*) as quantity, count(*) as estado, '=', 1')->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try query like this:

`$array = Tickets::groupBy('rrpp')->selectRaw('rrpp, count(*) as quantity, sum(case when estado = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as count_of_estado_1')->get();`